# Why Relu shows better convergence than Sigmoid Activation Function?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

Relu tends to show better convergence performance on gradient descent optimization than sigmoid activation function.
As far I came to know that when Z approaches less than 0 then updation with gradient descent becomes too slow, But relu has also gradient 0 when z is less than 0 then what is difference ?

Comment: [The following post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/126362/306148) explains pretty well.

Comment: Can you share a source ? I am not convinced this i s a general truth that relu show better convergence than sigmoid.

Comment: This is covered in the lecture of Andrew NG's deep learning courses. Week 2 of the first course Neural Network and Deep Learning.

Answer (score 2):

**Sigmoid**

[image]

$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$

$f'(x) = f(x)(1-f(x)) $

When the value of sigmoid function is either too high or too low, the derivative becomes too small(close to zero). While error is back propagating in sigmoid activated neural networks, gradient degradation happens and it results in vanishing gradient.

**Relu**

[image]

$f(x) = max(0,x) $
$f'(x) =  (0~if~x <0;1~if~x>0 )  $
While error is back-propagating in relu activated neural networks, gradient is not getting degraded.